# Require image in img tag with webpack

Tags: image, webpack

So far most tutorials I see have this code when it comes to images:

```
var imgElement = document.createElement('img');

imgElement.src = require('./images/my-image.jpg');

document.body.appendChild(imgElement);
```

However, how do I tell webpack to handle something like this in a template:

```
<img class="mhe-logo" src="../../assets/images/logo.png">
```

Is there special "require" syntax for inline links? Essentially, I would like to use the url-loader so that it returns a base64 of small images, and it hashes all other images.

Comment: What templating library/framework are you using?

Comment: @JoeClay using Angular, I know I can set the variable in my controller, but wondering if there's a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Depends how you're including the template - if it's hard coded into a directive as a string, you could use string interpolation, but if it's just a `.html` file I think the way forward is, as you said, to put the value in your controller, then you can use `ng-src` to bind to it. Here's a tip - when you bind to it, instead of doing `ng-src="{{ imageVar }}"`, use `ng-src="{{ ::imageVar }}"` - that'll make it a one time binding, so Angular won't waste time trying to check for changes to it.

Comment: However, you can add require('') in your JS file.